# Recordset Query using $_GET variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a user search form and a results page for querying a database. The query works perfect if the user enters in search criteria perfectly (passing variables using PHP). My question is: How can I make the SQL code query based on user input if it is not exactly what is in the database? I tried using the LIKE function with bookName but it does not work. Any help would be appreciative.

```
SELECT *
FROM book
WHERE authFName = colname OR authLName = varauthLName OR ISBN = varISBN OR bookName LIKE
varbookName OR Class_classNbr = varclassNumber
ORDER BY authLName ASC
```

Comment: Please post your actual code

Comment: Patrick, the code you see is from my Recordset on my results page. My search page sends this to my results page:  http://localhost/group3/resultsLO.php?authFName=&authLName=&ISBN=&curriculum=&classNumber=&bookName=Dreamweaver&submitSearch=Submit

Answer (score 0):

Try using '%' with the "Like" command. It works like a wildcard.

As :

```
LIKE '%varbookName%'
```

Comment: Works like a champ. Thanks a million!